# Is there a limit on the migration file size in Flyway?

Tags: flyway

We have massive reference data that we want to load when creating environments using Flyway. We can split it, but it will be useful to know if there is a limit on script file size in Flyway. 
I understand it's most probably related to memory and heap size, in this case, is there a way to calculate the maximum file size?

Answer (score 3):

Flyway Community Edition will load and parse your files in memory, so the heap size will be the biggest constraint.

Flyway Pro and Flyway Enterprise 5.1 and newer now also have the `flyway.stream` flag which makes Flyway stream the contents instead. This lets Flyway handle much larger files (multiple GBs are not an issue) with drastically lower memory requirements. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate#stream

Comment: You can sort of "cheat" on this by using Java migrations in the community edition, and streaming the files in yourself. However, if your migration is that large, you can also easily just split it into 2 migrations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, guys!